# Jersey response: don't set Content-Length header if Transfer-Encoding is already set

Tags: java, proxy, jersey-2.0, content-length, transfer-encoding

I have a Jersey-Application that proxies a request to an internal application, which should be out of direct access.

```
@GET
@Path("/path")
public static Response get(
        @Context UriInfo uriinfo,
        @Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
        byte[] body
        ) throws Exception{

//call the internal application
Response response = get(url, uriinfo, httpHeaders, body, HttpMethod.GET);

ResponseBuilder rb = Response.
                status(response.getStatusCode()).
                entity(response.getResponseStream());

//set all headers from response
for(header : response.getResponseHeaders()){
    rb.header(...);
}

Response r = rb.build();
//checking headers here, does NOT contain any Content-Length header
return r;
```

In the response, that comes from the internal application, there's the `Transfer-Encoding = chunked` header set. This is alright so far.

Now, the response that is sent to the client also contains the `Content-Length` header set, presumably by Jersey itself on the outgoing response. When I check the headers before I sent them to the client, all headers are set correctly like in the response from the internal app.

The `Content-Length` header causes the client to not interpret the response correctly, as there should be either  `Content-Length` or `Transfer-Encoding` set, as stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

How can I prevent Jersey from setting the `Content-Length` header, if I already have the Transfer-Encoding set?

Comment: Hi, just checking to see if you got any resolution to this issue?  Cheers, Rob.

Comment: @Rob Not the way, I expected to do it. My workaround was to remove the `Transfer-Encoding` header before sending the response to the client, which works for me so far.